# TypeScript - all ReturnTypes of functions contained in an object

Tags: typescript

```
const obj = {
   a: () => {a:2},
   b: () => "bar"
}

type ObjReturnTypes = ??? // {a:number} | "bar"
```

How do I extract from `obj` a union of all `ReturnTypes` of its nested functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) for this.

```
ReturnTypesUnion<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U : never;
}[keyof T]

type ObjReturnTypes = ReturnTypesUnion<typeof obj>
```

In plain English this type says "for every key of an object, if that key's value is a function then give me the return type of that function, and otherwise ignore it."

Comment: ObjReturnTypes is `{ a: { a: number}, b: string }`.  You need to do `type result = ObjReturnTypes[keyof ObjReturnTypes];`.  I think.

Comment: Stupid mistake, thank you!  I’m on my phone so I didn’t actually test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you want, as it returns `string | { a: number }`, but close.

```
const obj = {
    a: () => ({ a: 2 }),
    b: () => "bar",
}
type ObjReturnTypes = { [K in keyof typeof obj]: ReturnType<typeof obj[K]> }[keyof typeof obj];
```

Note that you have to put the first lambda return value in obj (`{ a: 2 }`) into parentheses or TypeScript thinks it's a function block.